# Blackberry 10 : How to get twitter feeds in native SDK with twitter API v1.1?

Tags: twitter, blackberry-10, native-code, twitter-feed

I am new in Blackberry 10, I want to load twitter feeds into my `ListView`.

I already got the sample of this, but its twitter API v1 which is out date now.

So anyone please help me that how to implement same with twitter API v1.1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? URL? Loading?

Comment: I am trying to fetch Twitter feeds by this url but I am getting error.  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=MyScreenName

Comment: It's some [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq) issue. Apparently you need to log in to access API. I hope someone else can help you here

Answer (score 1):

use this twitterbb10 app, it worked for me fine.

https://github.com/kylefowler/twitter-bb10